# What are the Issues that will Occur if I run multiple Tomcat in same Server?

Tags: server, tomcat7, tomcat8

I wanted to run tomcat 7 and tomcat 8 in my server. I wanted to know what are the thing that I should take care if I am doing the same.

Answer (score 0):

So long as you install to different directories and adjust the server.xml settings so they run on different ports there should not be a problem.